# Why do I see permalinks instead of slugs on Google? (i.e. /q/ and /a/)

Tags: bug, status-completed, google, seo, permalink

Lately, I've seen many search results in the form of `https://stackoverflow.com/q/<id>` and `/a/<id>` on Google. Why do I see these slug-less permalinks instead of the full URL?

For instance, a search for ["google search max url length"](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20search%20max%20url%20length) gives [`https://stackoverflow.com/a/41718`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4171844) instead of [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers):

> [image: google search result]

For the record, it seems that Google has indexed [1.7M slugless questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com/q) and [3.2M slugless answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com/a).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It was a simple mistake. The code that renders the head tags was refactored to support Twitter cards, that need the open graph equivalent of `<link rel="canonical"/>`.

The code to set the canonical URL was there, but in the wrong rendering section, so when the link was rendered, no value was yet present and nothing got written.

I've fixed it and it's now in the right place. Of course, it will take a little time for Google to catch up.

Comment: I still don't see `<link rel="canonical">` in the source of (M)SO. Did you already publish the fix?

Comment: No. that has not happened yet.

Comment: @RobW It's now on meta, I'm letting it bake for a few to make sure it's not breaking stuff.

Comment: @Sklivvz thanks for the explanation; I looked for the answer a good deal but wasn't phrasing it the right way I guess...

Answer (score 12):

I noticed something that might explain this behavior.

Somewhere between September 15 this year (2013) and September 23, the dev team removed the [Canonical link element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) that used to be on all questions pages.

How I figured this? Here is an [archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20130915104459/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works) of a question from September 15 and the same question [eight days later](http://web.archive.org/web/20130923062859/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works/) - view the source of both to see the `<link rel="canonical" ...>` gone.

As for why it was removed I fear only a dev can answer. Maybe a simple mistake, maybe on purpose.

Comment: Nice work, detective!

Comment: @AaronBertrand yeah, time traveling detective! ;-)